# ASP.NET Core 2.1 strange submenu appears in Manage page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

This is my Manage page that was generated by the Scaffolded Identity.

Previously this weird Manage your account header with the subheading: Change your account settings and menu did not appear.

The only thing that showed was the form in the image and the Manage Account header located directly above the form but I'm not sure why suddenly this extra header and menu appears. I've tried searching on the page itself but it doesn't show up in the code. Is this a configuration somewhere?

[image]

EDIT:

Added structure of Manage 
[image]

Comment: `Manager your account header and menu did not appear` vs `the only thing that showed was the form and the Manage Account header` I've tried to read multiple times but I couldnot understand what it is. What is your question?

Comment: Sorry, I've edited the question. My Manage Account form has been pushed down by the Manage your account header and menu located on the left of the page.

Comment: Is it a new scaffold or did you do an upgrade scaffold? The Identity UI in 2.0 and before was in MVC Views. The new Identity UI is based on razor pages and has a different folder structure. If upgrading and you did not do a lot of customizations, its best to delete the old views and then do a clean scaffold. Otherwise if you had heavy customizations, keep the MVC based UI

Comment: Check [ASP.NET Core Migration Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/20_21?view=aspnetcore-2.1) and [Scaffold identity into an MVC project with authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio#scaffold-identity-into-an-mvc-project-with-authorization)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to open the file `_Layout.cshtml` in the folder `Manage`, maybe there is something like this:

```
<h2>Manage your account</h2>

<div>
    <h4>Change your account settings</h4>
    <hr />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <partial name="_ManageNav" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            @RenderBody()
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
}
```

---

Based on your update, I think the problem comes from the way you add scaffolded item.

I suggest you to follow these steps to add all scaffolded items, then deleting which one you don't use.

1. Right-click on the solution -> Add -> New Scaffolded Item... -> Identity -> Identity -> Add
2. Check with the option: `Override all files`.

[image: 1]

3. In the layout input, clicking on the `...` button to select the default layout:

[image: 2]

4. In the `Data context class` input, clicking on `+` button to create new context class:

[image: 3]

After scaffolding, you will receive all the files:

[image: 4]

---

Lastly, you can open the file `_Layout.cshtml` to check the title, the file content could be:

```
@{ 
    Layout = "/Areas/Identity/Pages/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Manage your account</h2>

<div>
    <h4>Change your account settings</h4>
    <hr />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <partial name="_ManageNav" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            @RenderBody()
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
}
```

Comment: It's strange though, I dont have a _Layout.cshtml in my Manage folder. Ill edit my question to show

Comment: @JianYA Then, checking in the file `Index.cshtml`, is there something like `<h4>@ViewData["Title"]</h4>`? Or `Layout = "..."`?

Comment: I checked as well. Nothing there.