# How to create Partial View Login and Register in Asp.Net Core 2.1 application

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I am customizing the index of my application and would like to insert Partial View to login and register, but Asp.Net Core 2.1 does not create these views by default.

[image]

Inside the Areas folder, Identity does not create anything related to login and register.

The question is how do I create the partialview _Login and _ Register

Noting that I created the project for individual authentication, .Net Core and Asp.Net Core 2.1

See the image below that the Identity folder does not create the Partial Views Login and Register, is it possible to see visual studio when creating the project?
When I run in IIS Express it works perfectly and creates the database

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I cannot *see* them in the folder `Area/Idenity/Pages/...`. They were generated in *Razor Class Library*.

Source: [Create reusable UI using the Razor Class Library project in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/ui-class?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio)

You can add some scaffolded item(s) to the folder but I suggest you to add all of the items rather than 1 or 2 items at the same time.

I have a post here, you can follow these steps to generate them:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/53358476/10550549

If you have already a DbContext class, you don't have to create new one, just clicking on the dropdown and selecting one.